# Differentiate with product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question: differentiate $x(x^2 +3x)^3$

I have gotten to the point where i've used the product rule and i've gotten

$$(x^2 + 3x)^3 + x\cdot(3x+9)(x^2 + 3x)^2$$

but now that it comes to the simplifying im completely at a loss, any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: I think that the correct answer should be $(x^2 +3x)^3 + x(6x +9) (x^2 + 3x)^2$

Comment: A tip that might be useful: It is handsome here to state first that: $$x(x^2+3x)^3=x^4(x+3)^3$$ Applying the productrule on RHS you come to: $$4x^3(x+3)^3+3x^4(x+3)^2=x^3(x+3)^2(4(x+3)+3x)=x^3(x+3)^2(7x+12)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the product rule is not enough.

$$(x(x^2 + 3x)^3)^\prime = (x)^\prime \cdot (x^2 + 3x)^3 + x \cdot ((x^2 + 3x)^3)^\prime$$
$$=  (x^2 + 3x)^3 + x \cdot ((x^2 + 3x)^3)^\prime$$

For the rigth part you need to use the chain rule.

$$=  (x^2 + 3x)^3 + x \cdot 3(x^2 + 3x)^2\cdot(x^2+3x)^\prime$$
$$=  (x^2 + 3x)^3 + x \cdot 3(x^2 + 3x)^2\cdot(2x+3)$$

Now you can simplifying the result:
$$=  (x^2 + 3x)^2 \cdot \left((x^2 + 3x) + x \cdot 3\cdot(2x+3)\right)$$
$$=  (x^2 + 3x)^2 \cdot \left(x^2 + 3x + 6x^2 + 9x\right)$$
$$=  (x^2 + 3x)^2 \cdot \left(7x^2 + 12x\right)$$

Comment: how would i simplify this to $x^3(7x+12)(x+3)^2$ ?

Comment: You can single out an $x$ from $(7x^3 + 12x)$ and another 2 from $(x^2 + 3x)$.

Comment: Correction: You can single out a $x$ in $(x^2+3x)$, but it get's squared.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the product rule is defined as
\[
\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)\cdot g(x)]=f(x)\frac{d}{dx}[g(x)]+g(x)\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]
\]
And the chain rule is defined as
\[
f(x)=g(h(x))
\]
\[
\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]=\frac{d}{dx}[g(h(x))] \frac{d}{dx}[h(x)]
\]
So now here are the steps 
\[
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x(x^{2}+3x)^{3}\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^{4}(x+3)^{3}\right] =x^{4}\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+3)^{3}\right]+(x+3)^{3}\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^{4}\right]
\]
\[
=3x^{4}(x+3)^{2}\frac{d}{dx}[x+3]+4x^{3}(x+3)^{3}=3x^{4}(x+3)^{2}+4x^{3}(x+3)^{3}
\]
\[
=x^{3}(x+3)^{2}(3x+4x+12)=x^{3}(x+3)^{2}(7x+12)
\]

Answer (score 0):

Use the $\color{red}{\text{product rule}}$ and the $\color{blue}{\text{chain rule}}$
$$\begin{array}{rcl}(x(x^2+3x)^3)' &\color{red}{=}& x'\cdot (x^2+3x)^3+((x^2+3x)^3)'\cdot x \\ &\color{blue}{=}& (x^2+3x)^3+x(3(x^2+3x)^2\cdot (x^2+3x)') \\ &=& (x^2+3x)^3+x(3(x^2+3x)^2(2x+3))\\ &=& (x^2+3x)^3+3x(x^2+3x)^2(2x+3)\\ &=&x^3 (x+3)^2 (7 x+12) \end{array}$$

Comment: [here are the rules in question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Elementary_rules_of_differentiation)